# Writing to a certain row/column using XLWT

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

My data is in the form of a list of lists and I would like to begin writing the data in row 1, column zero.  I am using the xlwt library.

```
def to_spreadsheets(data_one):
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet_one = workbook.add_sheet("July 2013 Stats")


    data_one_trimmed = data_one['rows']

    for rownum, sublist in enumerate(data_one_trimmed):
        for colnum, value in enumerate(sublist):
            sheet_one.write(rownum, colnum, value)
```

This code writes my data to row 0, column 0 as I would like it to, but I have no idea how to change the location of where it writes to.

I tried `sheet_one.write(1, 0, rownum, colnum, value)`, but it obviously did not work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jon Clements Really? It is writing to 0, 0 and I need it to write to 1, 0? Is it not clear enough?

Comment: Ahh, I see. Well this did the trick `for rownum, sublist in enumerate(data_one_trimmed, 1):`

Comment: You can put it as an answer.  I didn't even know I could self-answer.  Will keep in mind for next time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to "offset" a row/column by some value, you can use a second argument to `enumerate` which is where it starts counting. `enumerate` will start from 0 by default, but you can start it from 1 (or any integer value) using its second argument, eg: `enumerate(some_iterable, 1)`.

The docs are https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate which states:

**enumerate(sequence, start=0)**

> Return an enumerate object. sequence must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration. The next() method of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over sequence: